# RDSH logon is hanging at 'Please wait for remote desktop configuration'

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, rds, session, remote-desktop-gateway

RDSH logon is hanging at 'Please wait for remote desktop configuration'.

Can anybody tell me what it's actually doing at this stage?

It will proceed eventually but we're talking like 5-10 minutes of wait time.

Comment: Are you using User Profile Disk ? if yes, check if the profiles' share is still available.
Have you tried restarting the server?
You should check the Windows events logs too